# Soapui how to extract a certain value form json response

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am trying to extract value of `dsId`, but not able to do that.

Please find below details.

Groovy Script which I am working is :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
log.info response

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText response
log.info json
log.info json.New England Schools__NE Schools$.dsId
```

but getting below error

[image]

My json response is below. I also want to extract value of ZIP.

```
{
  "New England Schools__NE Schools$": {
    "dsId": "ds_608",
    "type": "Account",
    "numericCols": [
      "ZIP",
      "Count Free Lunch",
      "Count Reduced Lunch",
      "Total Lunch Pgm",
      "Total Students",
      "PreKindergarten",
      "Kindergarten",
      "Grade 1",
      "Grade 2",
      "Grade 3",
      "Grade 4",
      "Grade 5",
      "Grade 6",
      "Grade 7",
      "Grade 8",
      "Grade 9",
      "Grade 10",
      "Grade 11",
      "Grade 12"
    ],
    "data": null,
    "AggNumericData": [
      {
        "ZIP": 19949795,
        "Count Free Lunch": 263596,
        "Count Reduced Lunch": 71799,
        "Total Lunch Pgm": 331987,
        "Total Students": 1796594,
        "PreKindergarten": 36553,
        "Kindergarten": 151898,
        "Grade 1": 164370,
        "Grade 2": 169418,
        "Grade 3": 173748,
        "Grade 4": 175505,
        "Grade 5": 179357,
        "Grade 6": 177978,
        "Grade 7": 174655,
        "Grade 8": 170192,
        "Grade 9": 178423,
        "Grade 10": 162045,
        "Grade 11": 147564,
        "Grade 12": 133368
      }
    ],
    "MinMax": [],
    "dsData": "Account Id#%#Territory#%#District#%#Area#%#Region#%#objname#%#~ID~#%#~Lat-Lon Linked~#%#~Latitude~#%#~Longitude~#%#~Lat-Lon Zip~#%#School Name#%#Address#%#City#%#State#%#ZIP#%#ZIP4#%#School Type#%#Status#%#School Level#%#Count Free Lunch#%#Count Reduced Lunch#%#Total Lunch Pgm#%#Total Students#%#PreKindergarten#%#Kindergarten#%#Grade 1#%#Grade 2#%#Grade 3#%#Grade 4#%#Grade 5#%#Grade 6#%#Grade 7#%#Grade 8#%#Grade 9#%#Grade 10#%#Grade 11#%#Grade 12#%#Territory1#%#Region1#%#lat#%#lon#%#terrid\r\n15709#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#Unassigned#%#Unassigned#%#Account#%#15709#%#True#%#41.934711#%#-72.770021#%#06026#%#R. DUDLEY SEYMOUR SCHOOL#%#185 HARTFORD AVENUE#%#EAST GRANBY#%#CT#%#6026#%#9520#%#1#%#1#%#2#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#131#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#60#%#71#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#5151204.33051376#%#-8100721.57141633#%#3\r\n15707#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#Unassigned#%#Unassigned#%#Account#%#15707#%#True#%#41.934894#%#-72.730656#%#06026#%#EAST GRANBY HIGH SCHOOL#%#95 SOUTH MAIN STREET#%#EAST GRANBY#%#CT#%#6026#%#9550#%#1#%#1#%#3#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#219#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#57#%#55#%#53#%#54#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#5151231.26605957#%#-8096340.03625871#%#3\r\n15708#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#Unassigned#%#Unassigned#%#Account#%#15708#%#True#%#41.934894#%#-72.730656#%#06026#%#EAST GRANBY MIDDLE SCHOOL#%#95 SOUTH MAIN STREET#%#EAST GRANBY#%#CT#%#6026#%#9550#%#1#%#1#%#2#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#201#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#67#%#73#%#61#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#5151231.26605957#%#-8096340.03625871#%#3\r\n15706#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#Unassigned#%#Unassigned#%#Account#%#15706#%#True#%#41.944215#%#-72.732696#%#06026#%#ALLGROVE SCHOOL#%#33 TURKEY HILLS ROAD#%#EAST GRANBY#%#CT#%#6026#%#9570#%#1#%#1#%#1#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#275#%#3#%#69#%#65#%#82#%#56#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#5152627.52929053#%#-8096567.12801993#%#3\r\n15710#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#Unassigned#%#Unassigned#%#Account#%#15710#%#True#%#41.944215#%#-72.732696#%#06026#%#HOMEBOUND#%#33 TURKEY HILL ROAD#%#EAST GRANBY#%#CT#%#6026#%#674#%#4#%#3#%#4#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#5152627.52929053#%#-8096567.12801993#%#3\r\n15923#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#Unassigned#%#Unassigned#%#Account#%#15923#%#True#%#42.0027#%#-72.942#%#06027#%#HOMEBOUND#%#30 SOUTH ROAD#%#EAST HARTLAND#%#CT#%#6027#%#9710#%#4#%#3#%#4#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#5161383.89953631#%#-8119866.29744296#%#3\r\n15922#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#Unassigned#%#Unassigned#%#Account#%#15922#%#True#%#42.0027#%#-72.942#%#06027#%#HARTLAND ELEMENTARY SCHOOL#%#30 SOUTH ROAD#%#EAST HARTLAND#%#CT#%#6027#%#9710#%#1#%#1#%#1#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#2#%#0#%#25#%#17#%#26#%#29#%#37#%#36#%#38#%#35#%#40#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#0#%#Hartford, CT#%#New England#%#5161383.89953631#%#-8119866.29744296#%#3\r\n16335#%#}
```

In dsData you can see that there are some column names with values, how can I extract column specific data ?

Comment: hi @ rao plz have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007809/soapui-how-to-extract-column-specific-data-form-the-json-response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got very trivial error.

Couple of things:

- The property has got space characters : so it needs to be enclosed within quotes
- There is `$` as well which needs to be escaped.

Here is the statement which can retrieve the required value of `dsId`

**Change your last statement from :**

`log.info json.New England Schools__NE Schools$.dsId`

**To:**

`log.info json."New England Schools__NE Schools\$".dsId`

Hope this helps.

**Update**

Just noticed that you wanted to extract `ZIP` value which is happen to be the property of first element in the array `AggNumericData`. Earlier, this question in your post was not visible or I overlooked. So updating the same in my answer.

Here is the statement to get the same:

`log.info ​json."New England Schools__NE Schools\$".AggNumericData[0].ZIP​`

**UPDATE 2:** Author of the problem mentioned, he is not not able get data together in his comment. So, adding here how to get both. Note that, I had to use minimum data to reproduce it since only part of the `json` was provided.

Getting both request data

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks Buddy first of all very thanks for quick reply i am able to find dsId  with your solution but when trying to get zip the getting below error something like this startup failed: Script17.groovy: 9: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ​json . At [9:10] @ line 9, column 10. log.info ​json."New England Schools__NE Schools\$".AggNumericData[0].ZIP ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ​json . At [9:10] @ line 9, column 10. at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$15.call(CompilationUnit.java:760)

Comment: As per your sample, i got the zip with given statement. But your actual request might be differ from the one that you provided ?and causing that? You want to provide more info?

Comment: HI very strange when i use only zip finding code its working but when i use both at the same time its not working

Comment: Hey it worked i deleted the existing assertion and created new one and it worked Thanks for your help buddy you are awesome

Comment: Updated answer with a screen shot

Comment: May be while copy paste, any special character got appended and that is causing problem? Try to copy it in a text editor such as notepad and remove it from soapUI and copy the script back from notepad to see if that help. I had similar experience when copy pasted from browser.